IIS is not using GPU
We have written blender python script which is used for creating stl file. This script is working fine and using GPU when we are running it using command line. We have integrated script in c# code and code is deployed on IIS. On IIS server script is not using GPU and create malformed object sometime. Can we call GPU within IIS server? Please help me.
Below is the C# code:
using (var process = new Process())
{
    string command = string.Empty;
    command = @"--debug-all --background --python " + "\"" + scriptFilePath + "\"" + " " + "\"" + stlFilePath + "\"" + " "
        + "\"" + newStlFilePath + "\"" + " " + "\"" + fileName + "\"" + " "
        + rows + " " + columns + " " + numberofcoin + " \"" + coinDiameter + "\"" + " \"" + printerTypeId + "\"" + " \"" + objectType + "\"";

    process.StartInfo.FileName = blenderExePath;
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = $"{command}";
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

    process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, data) => Console.WriteLine(data.Data);
    //process.OutputDataReceived += (Object _sender, DataReceivedEventArgs _args) => Process_OutputDataReceived(_sender, _args);
    //process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, data) => Console.WriteLine(data.Data);
    process.ErrorDataReceived += (Object _sender, DataReceivedEventArgs _args) => Process_ErrorDataReceived(_sender, _args);

    //Console.WriteLine("starting");
    process.Start();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();
    process.WaitForExit(1000 * 5); // (optional) wait up to 5 seconds
}


What user is running your IIS application pool?

You cannot skip the differences, https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

@gunr2171 IIS application pool is running with administrator rights.

This problem may be because Blender cannot access the GPU normally under the IIS environment, causing the generated STL file to sometimes appear abnormal, implement logging in your script to confirm whether the GPU is being detected and utilized when run through IIS. You can use Blender's Python API to print GPU usage information.
